# Redirect to specific URL after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way in Devise 1.0, the library for Rails 2.3, to redirect to a specific URL and not root_url after logging in?

**EDIT: forgot to mention it's Devise 1.0**

Answer (score 21):

Chances are that your user is being redirected before `after_sign_in_path` is called. This happens if the user tries to go to a page that is protected by authentication directly. This will happen all the time if you have your `root_path` ('/') protected by authentication.

There's a discussion on google groups about this topic:

- http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/454c7ea651601a6c/64f0adc3be8036d0?#64f0adc3be8036d0

The quick and dirty solution is to overwrite `stored_location_for` to always return `nil` like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base  
...

  private 
  def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
    nil
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    my_favorite_path
  end
end
```

Comment: As a slight variation on this, I only return nil from stored_location_for if it matches '/' which is my default route. That way they will go to after_sign_in_path only if they weren't explicitly trying to go somewhere else. To do that just replace nil with "(location = super) == '/' ? nil : location".

Answer (score 4):

I think the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in Devise is what you're looking for.

Define that method in your ApplicationController and it will over-ride Devise's default implementation. This is what the documentation specifies to do.

Details here: http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for

Comment: I've forgot to mention in Devise 1.0, not 1.1.

Comment: after_sign_in_path_for is not being called on 1.0.8 at all.

Comment: Looking at Devise's SessionsController, when login is successful, sign_in_and_redirect is called. This redirects to the previous location stored in the session. If no location is stored, then after_sign_in_path_for is called.

Is the user logging in from (or via) the homepage? That could explain why it always redirects back there.

Comment: Then, why didn't adding raise to that method didn't cause it to stop the request?

Comment: Which method did you add raise to - sign_in_and_redirect? Are you using the default Devise controllers/views or have you overwritten any parts of them?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to show user's dashboard after logging in.

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController    
    def index
       if current_user //returns nil if not logged in
          @users = User.all
          render :dashboard
       end
    end

    def dashboard
       @users = User.all
    end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'homes#index'
```

If logged in, if-block is entered in index action and dashboard.erb is rendered.
(make sure to initialize all variables, required by dashboard.erb, in your if-block)
Otherwise rails renders index.erb