# Have different view based on type of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a user model that has a few different types, i.e. there is a user attribute that is set as either a usertype1, usertype2, or usertype3.  How can I route the user to a different page based on the user type?  I am using devise for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user after logging in then check this [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in). The specific code is

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if usertype1?
    some_url
  elsif usertype2?
    another_url
  elsif usertype3?
    some_other_url
  end
end
```

But if what you're looking for is more generic then that you probably want to define roles and give users access to certain parts of the site based on their roles - also known as *authorization*. For that I'd recommend using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). You can also watch the [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) if you want more info.

**Edit:**

See also this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636112/redirect-to-specific-url-after-logging-in)

Comment: I am not clear on what "If you are using a gem that reads to URI for certain processing (like simple-navigation) " means from the devise wiki link you provided, but I don't think this code solves my problem of wanting to redirect the user based on what type of user the user is.  I am not worried about before_filters with authorization at this point, but thank you for the tips and links.

Comment: @John WHEN do you want to redirect your users? If it's at all times then you're talking about authorization.

Comment: I would like to redirect users after log-in.

Comment: @John  I also edited the code so hopefully you can understand it.