# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. How to change the after login redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin app. When the user logs in, it is taken to `/admin` but I would like to change the redirection to something else `/admin/custom_dashboards`

I was able to change the redirection of access denied errors with this

```
application_controller.rb
--------------------------
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to admin_custom_dashboards_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

But I want to change the redirection after login, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: [Redirect to specific URL after logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636112/redirect-to-specific-url-after-logging-in)

I just added the following to application_controller.rb

```
application_controller.rb
-------------------------
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  admin_favorite_path # customize to your liking
end
```